# Amazon AWS Beanstalk IP based throttling

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rate-limiting

I've deployed a web app using Amazon AWS beanstalk. Could someone please throw some light on how AWS takes care of IP based throttling?

Earlier when I had my own tomcat instance running on EC2, I was using iptables for this purpose. But, now I'm confused about how to achieve this since AWS scales my webapp on multiple machines based on the load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, internally Beanstalk is Cloudformation stack, which includes: loadbalancer, autoscalling group ans pre configured ami with tomcat.

You have two option how to implement throttling:
1. Setup iptables rules with help of EB configuration files: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
2. Create custom ami. Described:http://blog.jetztgrad.net/2011/02/how-to-customize-an-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance/

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195279/aws-beanstalk-could-not-run-commands-using-config-file) and let me know if you've any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @KiranN Let me know what did you find:)

Comment: Hi. I got the config file commands working. But, I realized that this is not going to solve the problem I have. Let me explain you what I'm trying to do. I wanted to setup IP based throttling on port 80 to avoid DDoS attack. But, now, since I'm throttling that port on my EC2 machine via config commands, my load balancer which talks to EC2 on that port gets throttled. You've suggested to use iptables. But, based on my understanding, throttling should be set at load balancer level. Is my understanding correct? Could you please provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: You understanding is correct, but unfortunately elastic loadbalancer does not provide managed request throttling functionality, that why you have two options: 1. instead of ELB use haproxy or something like. 2. Apply firewall rule on ec2 instances.