# AWS Beanstalk - could not run commands using config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Tomcat 7 setup using beanstalk. I am trying to run the following commands on that environment by placing the commands in .config(yaml) file as shown below:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 5 -j DROP
```

config file
commands:

```
sudodisable:
command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty
ipbasedthrotllingcommand1:
command: sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --set
ipbasedthrotllingcommand2:
command: sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 5 -j DROP
```

Here are my inferences:

1) I followed the advice here in this thread --> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=395894 and put the above shown content in my .config file and uploaded my .war only to get the following error

```
2013-03-03 20:52:39,165 DEBUG Not setting a reboot trigger as scheduling support is not available
2013-03-03 20:52:39,185 INFO Running configSets: deque()
2013-03-03 20:52:39,187 INFO Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2013-03-03 20:52:39,187 INFO Running config prebuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application_sudofix__ebextensions_testit_config
2013-03-03 20:52:39,187 DEBUG No packages specified
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG No groups specified
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG No users specified
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG No sources specified
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG No files specified
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG Running command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1
2013-03-03 20:52:39,188 DEBUG No test for command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1
2013-03-03 20:52:39,204 ERROR Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 (sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --set) failed
2013-03-03 20:52:39,205 DEBUG Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 output: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
2013-03-03 20:52:39,205 ERROR Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application_sudofix__ebextensions_testit_config: Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 505, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 241, in build
changes = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 103, in apply
raise ToolError("Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 failed
2013-03-03 20:52:39,206 ERROR Unhandled exception during build: Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 135, in <module>
worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 496, in build
self.run_config(config, worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 505, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 241, in build
changes = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 103, in apply
raise ToolError("Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command ipbasedthrotllingcommand1 failed
2013-03-03 20:53:26,362 DEBUG CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
2013-03-03 20:53:26,362 DEBUG Describing resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:726941363581:stack/awseb-e-jiipcgeknm-stack/3bb8eac0-842f-11e2-b50d-50690881bc86
2013-03-03 20:53:26,577 DEBUG Not setting a reboot trigger as scheduling support is not available
2013-03-03 20:53:26,593 INFO Running configSets: deque()
2013-03-03 20:53:26,595 INFO Running configSet InfoTask-TailLogs
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 INFO Running config InfoTask-TailLogs
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 DEBUG No packages specified
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 DEBUG No groups specified
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 DEBUG No users specified
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 DEBUG No sources specified
2013-03-03 20:53:26,596 DEBUG No files specified
2013-03-03 20:53:26,597 DEBUG Running command taillogs
2013-03-03 20:53:26,597 DEBUG No test for command taillogs
```

2) If I run the iptables commands without sudo, I dont see them getting executed at all. Basically I dont even see the references to the .config file in my log files, which makes me doubt if the config file is even picked up.

I would really appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: Try to log in to EB EC2 instance and try to run command by hands:) This will help to catch root of error.

Comment: Also you should now two important thinks: 
1. Command from .ebextentions runs under root user;
2. "commands"  are run before the application and web server are set up, and before the application is extracted. 

So, I still recommed to connect to server by ssh and try to run scripts manually.

Comment: Sure @Vadim911. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty
```

is wrong. Based on the docs that you linked to, it should be:

```
echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
```